# swapon: stat of /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 failed: No such file or directory

Tags: partitioning, swap, cryptswap

I have an issue with creating encrypted swap.

I follow these steps

1. `sudo swapoff -a`
2. Comment existing swap configuration in `/etc/crypttab`
3. Comment existing swap configuration in `/etc/fstab`
4. Re-format swap partition with gparted as linux-swap
5. `sudo mkswap /dev/sda5`
6. Update `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` with the new UUID
7. `sudo update-initramfs -u`
8. `sudo swapon /dev/sda5`
9. `sudo ecryptfs-setup-swap`

And at that point I encounter this problem

```
root@username-UX430UN:/home/username# ecryptfs-setup-swap
WARNING:
An encrypted swap is required to help ensure that encrypted files are not leaked to disk in an unencrypted format.

HOWEVER, THE SWAP ENCRYPTION CONFIGURATION PRODUCED BY THIS PROGRAM WILL BREAK HIBERNATE/RESUME ON THIS SYSTEM!

NOTE: Your suspend/resume capabilities will not be affected.

Do you want to proceed with encrypting your swap? [y/N]: y

INFO: Setting up swap: [/dev/sda5]
marking GPT swap partition /dev/sda5 as no-auto...
swapon: stat of /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 failed: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same issue when trying to set up my encrypted swap space and think I've come to a solution. To get started here's a couple links that I used in my research:

- [Simple How-To](https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2012/05/23/ubuntu-how-to-encrypt-swap-partition/) encrypt swap space with ecryptfs (when everything works right)
- [Debugging Blog post](http://unixetc.co.uk/2016/03/20/linux-device-change-breaks-encrypt) that debugs a very similar problem in depth. I got a lot of my ideas from here, so I'd recommend giving it a read.

## Problem Setup

When I ran `ecryptfs-setup-swap` the first time (note that I had already set up swap space when I installed, so I didn't need to do the `mkswap` , I got an error message saying the swap space could not be mounted properly.

```
$ sudo ecryptfs-setup-swap                                                                       
[sudo] password for isaac:                                                                       

WARNING:                                                                                         
An encrypted swap is required to help ensure that encrypted files are not leaked to disk in an unencrypted format.

HOWEVER, THE SWAP ENCRYPTION CONFIGURATION PRODUCED BY THIS PROGRAM WILL BREAK HIBERNATE/RESUME ON THIS SYSTEM!

NOTE: Your suspend/resume capabilities will not be affected.                                     

Do you want to proceed with encrypting your swap? [y/N]: y                                       

INFO: Setting up swap: [/dev/nvme0n1p5]                                                          
WARNING: Commented out your unencrypted swap from /etc/fstab                                     
marking GPT swap partition /dev/nvme0n1p5 as no-auto...                                          
swapon: stat of /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 failed: No such file or directory
```

I tried to run the command again and got a message stating that I no longer had any swap space.

```
$ sudo ecryptfs-setup-swap                                                                       
INFO: You do not currently have any swap space defined.                                          

You can create a swap file by doing:                                                             
 $ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile count=130667600                                             
 $ sudo mkswap /swapfile                                                                         
 $ sudo swapon /swapfile                                                                         

And then re-run /usr/bin/ecryptfs-setup-swap
```

Double checking the error message from the first run of the ecrypt command, it does appear that `/dev/mapper/cryptswap1` does not exist.

```
$ ls /dev/mapper/                                                                                
control
```

## Investigating Relevant System Files

Based on the previously mentioned [blog](http://unixetc.co.uk/2016/03/20/linux-device-change-breaks-encrypt) post, I decided to start hunting around in my system files for evidence as to why the swap space wasn't being identified. The blog mentions that the changed naming schemes of hard drive partitions causes issues for ecryptfs and that switching over to using a UUID based identifier is more consistent.

```
$ blkid                                                                                          
/dev/nvme0n1p5: UUID="aea96d7f-e091-460b-95fd-a34ab884d440" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="0a7db4e0-17bf-40e3-8675-afec7891afc5"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL="ESP" UUID="C291-E533" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="63fc7fb9-2ca5-422b-90c7-0db698acdb3c"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="16F4C1EEF4C1D063" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="c04d0838-5570-4bfc-a961-4b9224b8cc0c"
/dev/nvme0n1p4: UUID="0EEE7736EE7714E5" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="4dc6595f-cc9c-4d80-99ab-ffd9cbe3c1d7"
/dev/nvme0n1p6: UUID="8b2f5c94-db79-4c8d-b5c6-403d912bc0dd" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="e373c83f-f992-4e62-a235-1fdd01ac7cf0"
```

Notice that my swap space is `/dev/nvme0n1p5` and has the UUID `aea96d7f...`. Now I'll take a look `/etc/fstab` and `/etc/crypttab` to see what the swap configuration looks like.

```
$ cat /etc/fstab                                                                                 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.                                                    
#                                                                                                
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a                                   
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices                       
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).                                  
#                                                                                                
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>                           
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p6 during installation                                                    
UUID=8b2f5c94-db79-4c8d-b5c6-403d912bc0dd /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1    
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation                                            
UUID=C291-E533  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1                                
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation                                                 
#UUID=aea96d7f-e091-460b-95fd-a34ab884d440 none            swap    sw              0       0     
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0                                                          


$ cat /etc/crypttab                                                                              
# <target name> <source device>         <key file>      <options>                                
cryptswap1 UUID=aea96d7f-e091-460b-95fd-a34ab884d440 /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

There are a couple things worth noting here, so I'll go through them one at a time.

- ecryptfs seems to have properly modified my `fstab` to disable my old swap space (commented out line with the swap UUID) and enable the encrypted one.
- The crypttab is set up with the appropriate UUID to map to my swap space. This is a big deal, if your crypttab is set up with something besides a UUID (say, the name of the drive in /dev), it's possible that the kernel could rename the drive and cause issues (again, see the [blog](http://unixetc.co.uk/2016/03/20/linux-device-change-breaks-encrypt) for details). In my case, ecryptfs seems to have set up the entry properly using a UUID (my guess is that it is patched on 16.04 as the blog mentions the problem on 14.04).
- The crypttab specifies an offset for the drive. Again, this is a subtle "gotcha" mentioned in the blog, but if the offset is not present, it can apparently cause your drive to lose it's UUID because it will get encrypted.

Finally, I checked `swapon` to see if it's finding any swap space.

```
$ swapon -s                                                                                      
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority                 
/dev/dm-0                               partition       31248892        0       -1
```

Looks like it is pointing to a swap space (of the correct size) but that swap space is not being properly set up within `/dev/mapper` (as referenced by fstab).

## Solution

Following the suggestions in the blog post, I decided to see if simply restarting the `cryptdisks` service would solve the issue.

```
$ swapoff -a                                                                                     

$ /etc/init.d/cryptdisks start                                                                   

$ swapon -a                                                                                      

$ swapon -s                                                                                      
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority                 
/dev/dm-0                               partition       31248892        0       -1               

$ ls -l /dev/mapper/                                                                             
total 0                                                                                          
crw------- 1 root root 10, 236 Jan  9 11:30 control                                              
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Jan  9 12:28 cryptswap1 -> ../dm-0
```

At this point it *seems* like my swap space is configured properly. Running `htop` shows the appropriate amount of swap space and the diagnostic commands that I was using above are all coming out positive, notably `blkid` now shows `/dev/mapper/cryptswap1`.

```
$ sudo blkid                                                                                     
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL="ESP" UUID="C291-E533" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="63fc7fb9-2ca5-422b-90c7-0db698acdb3c"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="16F4C1EEF4C1D063" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="c04d0838-5570-4bfc-a961-4b9224b8cc0c"
/dev/nvme0n1p4: UUID="0EEE7736EE7714E5" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="4dc6595f-cc9c-4d80-99ab-ffd9cbe3c1d7"
/dev/nvme0n1p5: UUID="aea96d7f-e091-460b-95fd-a34ab884d440" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="0a7db4e0-17bf-40e3-8675-afec7891afc5"
/dev/nvme0n1p6: UUID="8b2f5c94-db79-4c8d-b5c6-403d912bc0dd" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="e373c83f-f992-4e62-a235-1fdd01ac7cf0"
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1: UUID="113abaa7-c122-4d47-a826-181ee6a29627" TYPE="swap"
```

The settings persisted through reboot and everything seems to be running ok, so as far as I can tell, this worked. Hopefully this helps.

### Potential alternate solution

To make sure that my answer was working appropriately, I tried to replicate the problem on an EC2 instance. I had the same behavior where running `sudo ecryptfs-setup-swap` where it would error trying to run `swappon`. However, for some reason the device mapping `/dev/dm-0` did not seem to be set up properly. The `/etc` files seemed to be ok, so I tried simply rebooting the instance. This appeared to work just fine; however, I'd recommend at least inspecting the appropriate config settings before rebooting to make sure that they are set up correctly so the kernel can mount the swap when you reboot.

Comment: When executing `swapon -a` I get `swapon: stat of /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 failed: No such file or directory`

Comment: Yup, that's the same error I got when I was running on the EC2 instance (see the final section of my answer). I'd recommend checking over the `/etc` files but then go for a reboot. I've helped a couple of my coworkers through this process so far, and one of them had the same error pop up, a reboot fixed it for them though.

Comment: Issuing `sudo cryptdisks_start cryptswap1` fixed the error for me. It seems to be due to a bug in `ecryptfs-utils`.

Comment: @Farzan worked! but it assumes swapfile is named `/swapfile` and is in `/` - so if you have e.g. `/my/myswap` you have to rename(`mv`) it to `/swapfile`, then this command starts the crypto disk, then you can `swapon -a` and you can then verify by `sudo ecryptfs-setup-swap` and `ls -la /dev/mapper/cryptswap1` which should show it's a symlink  to some `dm-*` created by cryptodisks.

Answer (score 7):

Simple reboot fixed this problem for me.

Comment: I had to re-uncomment my original swap line in /etc/fstab then comment or remove the added line for the crypt-swap, then reboot, then rerun the command. Then it worked :)

Comment: @DivisiblebyZero but doesn't that just enable back the **unecrypted** swapfile?

Comment: @jave.web Sorry I don't even remember what this was about , and it's all mumbo jumbo to me now.