# ubuntu 20.04: green lines in background + crash at standby after upgrade

Tags: grub2, 20.04, suspend

I experience several odd errors and glinces after upgrading from ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04.

The first thing, I noticed were the **funny green pixeled lines on the background** wallpaper. They can be overlayed by windows and disappear when switching to a different image but remain on the original image, when switching back. This is also the case for other background images from the standard stock).

[image: screenshot]

Further -- and much more annoying -- is that **ubuntu repeatedly crashes at standby/when suspended**, e.g. when closing the lid. So, it won't wake up again or rather, it isn't asleep (blinking lights indicate the difference). When booting again, I can choose to start up in recovery mode ... I checked all packages and the file system, updated the boot-loader (2.04-1ubuntu26.6), etc.
In some cases, the system won't start up at all. I couldn't find a pattern yet.

I found [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032633/18-04-screen-remains-blank-after-wake-up-from-suspend/1041397#1041397) describing that the screen remains black after waking up, but adding the option `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.modeset=0"` to grub (`/etc/default/grub`) didn't help.

I am out of ideas. Some further info:

```
$ ls -al /var/crash
total 8
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie 4096 Feb  9  2020 .
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root     4096 Nov 14 11:04 ..
```

and

```
$ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Nov  5 22:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Nov  5 22:11 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov  5 22:00 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov  5 21:33 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov  5 21:34 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

and the system (Asus notebook -- no Nvidia graphics)

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 59)
```

Since there are usually not two separate root causes, I suspect that both errors are linked. Thx

**Update** I reconfigured my swap partition (see those two very informative posts on a step-by-step-guide [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978043/swapon-stat-of-dev-mapper-cryptswap1-failed-no-such-file-or-directory) and for encrypted swap [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341979/what-to-do-about-the-disk-drive-for-dev-mapper-cryptswap1-is-not-ready-yet-or)). Nevertheless, I still experience the problem. Further, after crashing at suspend, the system starts-up automatically. However, when choosing "ubuntu" from the recovery booting list, the screen remains black and no startup is visible.

Comment: this (and a package upgrade) indeed seem to have cured my problems. Thx =) Although I can follow why *xserver* causes the green pixels, I wonder why this has to do with crashes when suspending. Do you have an explanation for this?

Comment: Do graphics related software problems ever cause crashes when suspending? Yes, they certainly can cause segmentation faults and crashes when suspending. If both problems go away together then you will be lucky enough to have killed two birds with one stone. However it worries me that you have an encrypted swap partition in 20.04. New installations of 20.04 have a swap file not a swap partition by default.

Comment: uninstalling the `xserver-xorg-video-intel` cured the funny pixels. However, the BIOS problem remains and is more likely something similar to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233019/kernel-error-messages-when-booting-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: I have a gold [tag:software-installation] badge that lets me add other duplicate links to any question that has that tag if you find other duplicate links to add to this question.